# Running an msi from Docker. Which host OS should choose

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I want to create a docker container which installs an MSI application. I know i will be using the microsoft\widows\servercore image for this. Which host os i should use for this purpose. Will this image can be created and deployed in a Linux distribution??

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a Windows container, you need to use Docker on Windows.

In general, containers can only run on the OS that they're designed for, but it is possible using Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac to run Linux containers since they provide a miniature Linux VM to run those containers. However, Docker on non-Windows OSes doesn't provide a copy of Windows to run containers with, so you have to use Windows to run Windows containers.

If you want your container to be deployable on a Linux host, it will need to be using a Linux container image.